# Special case in proof of Holder's inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g$ are complex function in $\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and $p,q$ are positive real numbers such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Then $$\int \limits_{a}^{b}|fg|d\alpha\leqslant \left(\int \limits_{a}^{b}|f|^pd\alpha\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\int \limits_{a}^{b}|g|^qd\alpha\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}.$$

I have one question: In many papers and books assume that both right members is not zero then after it they uses Young's inequality and they get what we need.
But what about if $\int \limits_{a}^{b}|f|^pd\alpha=0$? They write that then $f\equiv 0$ almost everywhere. But it is problem from chapter 6 PMA Rudin and there is not such like "almost everywhere" and "set of zero measure" and I have no information about that. Can anyone explain it differently please?

By the way I found smt like this but I can't understand what does he mean
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show Holder works for finite sums; here there is no problem. Then note

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} |f(x_k)||g(x_k)|\Delta \alpha_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} [|f(x_k)|(\Delta \alpha_k)^{1/p}] [ |g(x_k)|(\Delta \alpha_k)^{1/q}] \le (\sum_{k=1}^{n} |f(x_k)|^p\Delta \alpha_k\,)^{1/p}(\sum_{k=1}^{n} |g(x_k)|^q\Delta \alpha_k\,)^{1/q}$$

Comment: I find it very useful. Can you explain your last inequality?

Comment: It's Holder for sums.

Comment: Dear zhw! Sorry but I have some problems with this: I proved what you wrote and move to $\inf$ and get: $U(P,|fg|,\alpha)\leqslant U(P,|f|^p,\alpha)^{\frac{1}{p}}U(P,|g|^q,\alpha)^{\frac{1}{q}}$. But how to get from that inequality Holder's inequality?

Comment: where $U(P,f,\alpha)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}M_i\Delta\alpha_i, M_i=\sup \limits_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f$ and $\inf U(P,f, \alpha)=\int \limits_{a}^{b}fd\alpha$ where $\inf$ taken over all partitions of $[a,b]$.

Comment: The integrals in question are as close as we want to the sums in my answer.

Comment: Dear zhw! Can you show it $\epsilon$ definition please? if it is not hard for you